# Set focus to the first listview item

Tags: c#, listview, focus, winui-3

In WinUI3 I need to set focus to the first item of ListView in order user could use the keyboard immediately. I do the following:

```
listView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

if (listView.Items.Count > 0) 
{
    listView.SelectedIndex = 0;                                     
}
```

But only the listview gets the focus, not the item and I need to click first on the item before I can go up and down with the keyboard. Is there any easy way to focus on the first item of the listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, `ListViewItem` can't be selected from the first time so here is some workaround for this problem:

```
ListViewItem lvi = listView.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListViewItem;

if (lvi != null) 
{
    lvi.IsSelected = true;
    lvi.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
} 
else 
{
    var dispatcherQueue = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
    dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(DispatcherQueuePriority.Low,
                        () => {
                            lvi = listView.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListViewItem;
                            if (lvi != null) {
                                lvi.IsSelected = true;
                                lvi.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                            }
                        });
}
```